# Acessing MySQL DB in a container from the host machine

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL DB running in a docker container.

It has the 3306 port,
the user root
and host mysql.

I now want to access this database via the MySQL workbench which is locally installed on my computer.

What do I have to insert as the Hostname parameter?

Comment: Have you tried localhost:3306 ?  Not sure if the addition of the Docker container complicates this or not.  If that doesn't work, try a cmd and then ipconfig and find out your actual IP and try that with the :PORT of :3306 on the end perhaps?

Comment: The problem is localhost:3306 Is the local connection on my machine, I might have to delete it. Adding docker makes this definitely more complicated but I have to use it for a project.

Comment: Well you want localhost:3306 to be the way to get to the MySQL server FROM the Server its self.  So what I think is that Docker is either on a different IP, OR its forwarding a port perhaps ..  but I'm just stabbing at the dark on that.

Comment: When using my local Ip it says: Host: '<my machines name>' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server. Which means the server seems to at least exist.

Comment: The default port for docker is 2375 (unencrypted) and 2376(encrypted) communication over tcp(although you can choose any other port).  Although after seeing your other comment, it sounds like you can hit the server, so you just need access now.

Comment: Ohhh you need a Root Login account on the MySQL server too .. is that setup?  You will want to use that ROOT user to access your database for full control.  You are going to need to pass the user name and the password to the server when you try to connect or you will be denied access.

Comment: You mean a root user for this specific database or one for all? because I already have one for local connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247393/discussion-between-luke33-and-easleyfixed).